# How to set a default value using the HTML Custom widget example in icCube?

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

Following the article in [the icCube documentation](https://www.iccube.com/support/how-to-your-first-html-widget/) I created this visualization on another schema. I have modified it a bit so you can also use the "on Row Click" event.

Changed the code of the After Render javascript code:

```
   // direct manipulation/substituion on DOM
   var $mWidget = $widget.find("#" + id);
   // to enable On Row Click
   $mWidget.click(function(r) {
            context.fireRowClick(r, 0);
            context.fireCellClick(r, 0);
        }.bind(this, r));
   // to add a class to show which one is selected
   $mWidget.click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.ic3a-container').find(".ic3a-mini-box").removeClass("iv-selected");
        $(this).addClass("iv-selected");
    });

   if (r == 0 ) { $mWidget.addClass("iv-selected");  } // to mimic selection of first at refresh
```

This script is working fine. But I have trouble setting a default value. For example, if I change a Filter setting and this visualization is refreshed, it defaults visually back to the 1st item, but the "On Row Click parameter, @{row}" is not reset to the 1st value.

- how can I synchronize the selected item with its visual display?
- is it also possible to retain the selected value after an update of a filter that it uses?

Enclosed, a working Report JSON based on Sales (paste this in Report Designer > Information > Report Code) :

> {"magic":"ic3sv1","classID":"ic3.ReportGutsWrapper","guts":{"ic3Rev":5086,"migrations":[0,3483,3979,4008,4052,4076,4138,4159,4164,4219,4270,4500,4514,4927,4996,5037,5048,5050,5074,5086],"global":{"schemaName":"Sales","cubeName":"Sales","themeId":"ic3-statos","discussions":{"allowedEvents":[],"allowedHierarchies":[],"commentsColor":"#C13988","discussionsFormat":"@d{ic3.discussions.options.discussions_format.extended}","discussionsMode":"@d{ic3.discussions.options.discussions_mode.public}","showDiscussionsMode":"@d{ic3.discussions.options.show_discussions.always}"}},"containers":{"layouts":{"magic":"ic3sv1","classID":"ic3.EntityArrayContainer","guts":{"entities":[{"magic":"ic3sv1","classID":"ic3.ReportLayout","guts":{"id":"desktop","name":"@d{ic3.layout.type.desktop}","type":"SinglePage","pages":[{"magic":"ic3sv1","classID":"ic3.ReportPage","guts":{"id":"p1","name":"@d{ic3.layout.page.main}","widgetsLayout":{"magic":"ic3sv1","classID":"ic3.FixedLayout","guts":{"widgetBoxes":{"wb54":{"magic":"ic3sv1","classID":"ic3.FixedLayoutBox","guts":{"rectangle":{"left":390,"top":80,"right":890,"bottom":480},"zIndex":101,"advanced":{},"boxType":"@d{ic3.fixed_layout_box.default}","header":"Custom Template","id":"wb54","widgetAdapterId":"w6"}},"wb57":{"magic":"ic3sv1","classID":"ic3.FixedLayoutBox","guts":{"rectangle":{"left":80,"top":80,"right":370,"bottom":350},"zIndex":106,"advanced":{},"boxType":"@d{ic3.fixed_layout_box.box_type.no_header}","id":"wb57","widgetAdapterId":"w9"}},"wb102":{"magic":"ic3sv1","classID":"ic3.FixedLayoutBox","guts":{"rectangle":{"left":910,"top":80,"right":1310,"bottom":480},"zIndex":107,"advanced":{},"header":"Article Sales for @{region} for @{row}","id":"wb102","widgetAdapterId":"w10"}}},"pageComponents":[],"grid":{"snap":true,"show":false,"size":10},"widgetGroups":[],"theme":"Statos"}}}}]}}]}},"widgets":{"magic":"ic3sv1","classID":"ic3.EntityMapContainer","guts":{"w6":{"classID":"ic3.HtmlTemplateWidgetAdapter","guts_":{"configState":3,"widgetSettingsManager":{"classID":"ic3.WidgetSettingsManager","guts_":{"desktop":{"data":{"classID":"ic3.QueryBuilderWidgetSettings","guts_":{"data":{"builderUid":"m3"},"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"data","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false}},"events":{"classID":"ic3.EventMapperWidgetSettings","guts_":{"data":{"classID":"ic3.EventWidgetMapper","guts_":{"ic3rowClick":"row","__ic3_widgetEventsDescription":{}}},"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"events","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false}},"navigation":{"classID":"ic3.NavigationWidgetSettings","guts_":{"data":{"classID":"ic3.NavigationStrategy","guts_":{"menuVisibility":{"back":true,"axisXChange":"All","axisYChange":"All","filter":"All","reset":true,"widget":true,"others":"All"}}},"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"navigation","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false}},"hooks":{"classID":"ic3.WidgetSettings","guts_":{"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"hooks","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false,"data":{}}},"data-render":{"classID":"ic3.WidgetSettings","guts_":{"data":{"options":{"initialHtml":"
>
> Insert your initial markup here
>
> ","html":"
>
> Insert your markup here
>
> ","afterTemplateUpdate":"function(context, node, props) {\n // debugger; //uncomment to debug using browser's debugger\n  \n // Jquery node for the widget\n $node = $(node).html(\"\"); \n // html code for our boc\n var htmlTemplate = \"\" + \"\" + \"\" + \"$value$\" + \"$valueLabel$\" + \"$valueDif$ $labelDif$ \" + \"\";\n                      \n  \n // the actual html node where we will insert the boxes \n var $widget = $node.find(\".ic3a-container\").empty();\n  \n // for each row create a box \n for (var r = 0, h = context.rowsCount; r < h; r++) { \n   // the field values for the box\n   var labelR = context.rowLabel(r);\n   var labelL = context.columnLabel(1);\n   var val = context.cellFValue(r, 0);\n   var valDiff = context.cellFValue(r, 1); \n   // this creates an uniqueId on the whole report\n   var id = ic3.uniqueId(\"ic3-mini-box\");\n  \n   // let's do a straight forward string substituion for all our parameters\n   var htmlWdiget = htmlTemplate.replace(\"$id$\",id).replace(\"$value$\",val)\n   .replace(\"$valueLabel$\",labelR).replace(\"$valueDif$\",valDiff).replace(\"$labelDif$\",labelL);\n    \n   // append the html code, now it's in the DOM (visible)\n   $widget.append(htmlWdiget); \n  \n   // for this parameters let's do a bit of JQuery, but a replace string\n   // would be fine too.\n   var color = props.backgroundColor(r,0);\n   var iconClassName = context.cellFValue(r, 2); \n  \n \n \t// direct manipulation/substituion on DOM\n   \tvar $mWidget = $widget.find(\"#\" + id);\n   \t// to enable On Row Click\n   \t$mWidget.click(function(r) {\n            context.fireRowClick(r, 0);\n            context.fireCellClick(r, 0);\n        }.bind(this, r));\n   \t// to add a class to show which one is selected\n   \t$mWidget.click(function() {\n        $(this).closest('.ic3a-container').find(\".ic3a-mini-box\").removeClass(\"iv-selected\");\n        $(this).addClass(\"iv-selected\");\n    });\n\n   \tif (r == 0 ) { $mWidget.addClass(\"iv-selected\");  } // to mimic selection of first at refresh\n\n    $mWidget.css('background-color', color);\n   \t$mWidget.find(\".fa\").addClass(iconClassName);\n   }\n}"},"config":{"options":[{"name":"Background Color","valueRef":"backgroundColor","type":"Color"}]},"preset":{"label":"@d{ic3.widget.widget_template.options.preset.default}","id":"default","proto":null},"backgroundColor":{"mode":"@d{ic3.color_mode.palette_for_categories}","colors":["#21b7c2","#12595e"],"isDefaultPalette":false,"alpha":0.9,"shouldReverse":true}},"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"data-render","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false}},"filtering":{"classID":"ic3.WidgetSettings","guts_":{"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"filtering","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false,"data":{}}},"user-menu":{"classID":"ic3.WidgetSettings","guts_":{"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"user-menu","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false}}}}},"ic3_name":"w5","dataRenderOptions":{"options":{"initialHtml":"
>
> Insert your initial markup here
>
> ","html":"
>
> Insert your markup here
>
> ","afterTemplateUpdate":"function(context, node, props) {\n // debugger; //uncomment to debug using browser's debugger\n  \n // Jquery node for the widget\n $node = $(node).html(\"\"); \n // html code for our boc\n var htmlTemplate = \"\" + \"\" + \"\" + \"$value$\" + \"$valueLabel$\" + \"$valueDif$ $labelDif$ \" + \"\";\n                      \n  \n // the actual html node where we will insert the boxes \n var $widget = $node.find(\".ic3a-container\").empty();\n  \n // for each row create a box \n for (var r = 0, h = context.rowsCount; r < h; r++) { \n   // the field values for the box\n   var labelR = context.rowLabel(r);\n   var labelL = context.columnLabel(1);\n   var val = context.cellFValue(r, 0);\n   var valDiff = context.cellFValue(r, 1); \n   // this creates an uniqueId on the whole report\n   var id = ic3.uniqueId(\"ic3-mini-box\");\n  \n   // let's do a straight forward string substituion for all our parameters\n   var htmlWdiget = htmlTemplate.replace(\"$id$\",id).replace(\"$value$\",val)\n   .replace(\"$valueLabel$\",labelR).replace(\"$valueDif$\",valDiff).replace(\"$labelDif$\",labelL);\n    \n   // append the html code, now it's in the DOM (visible)\n   $widget.append(htmlWdiget); \n  \n   // for this parameters let's do a bit of JQuery, but a replace string\n   // would be fine too.\n   var color = props.backgroundColor(r,0);\n   var iconClassName = context.cellFValue(r, 2); \n  \n \n \t// direct manipulation/substituion on DOM\n   \tvar $mWidget = $widget.find(\"#\" + id);\n   \t// to enable On Row Click\n   \t$mWidget.click(function(r) {\n            context.fireRowClick(r, 0);\n            context.fireCellClick(r, 0);\n        }.bind(this, r));\n   \t// to add a class to show which one is selected\n   \t$mWidget.click(function() {\n        $(this).closest('.ic3a-container').find(\".ic3a-mini-box\").removeClass(\"iv-selected\");\n        $(this).addClass(\"iv-selected\");\n    });\n\n   \tif (r == 0 ) { $mWidget.addClass(\"iv-selected\");  } // to mimic selection of first at refresh\n\n    $mWidget.css('background-color', color);\n   \t$mWidget.find(\".fa\").addClass(iconClassName);\n   }\n}"},"config":{"options":[{"name":"Background Color","valueRef":"backgroundColor","type":"Color"}]},"preset":{"label":"@d{ic3.widget.widget_template.options.preset.default}","id":"default","proto":null},"backgroundColor":{"mode":"@d{ic3.color_mode.palette_for_categories}","colors":["#21b7c2","#12595e"],"isDefaultPalette":false,"alpha":0.9,"shouldReverse":true}},"ic3_eventMapper":{"classID":"ic3.EventWidgetMapper","guts_":{"ic3rowClick":"row","__ic3_widgetEventsDescription":{}}},"ic3_uid":"w6"}},"w9":{"classID":"ic3.SelectControlAdapter","guts_":{"configState":3,"dataRenderOptions":{"type":{"label":"@d{ic3.widget.select_control.type.buttons_list}","id":"buttons","proto":{"chartType":"buttons"}},"styling":{"selectedTextBgColor":{"mode":"@d{ic3.color_mode.single_color}","colors":["#1a9641","#a6d96a","#ffffbf","#fdae61","#d7191c"],"isDefaultPalette":false,"color":"#61b8ac"}},"selectionMode":"single"},"widgetSettingsManager":{"classID":"ic3.WidgetSettingsManager","guts_":{"desktop":{"data":{"classID":"ic3.FilterQueryBuilderWidgetSettings","guts_":{"data":{"builderUid":"m1"},"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"data","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false}},"events":{"classID":"ic3.EventMapperWidgetSettings","guts_":{"data":{"classID":"ic3.EventWidgetMapper","guts_":{"ic3selection":"region","__ic3_widgetEventsDescription":{}}},"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"events","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false}},"hooks":{"classID":"ic3.WidgetSettings","guts_":{"data":{},"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"hooks","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false}},"data-render":{"classID":"ic3.WidgetSettings","guts_":{"data":{"type":{"label":"@d{ic3.widget.select_control.type.buttons_list}","id":"buttons","proto":{"chartType":"buttons"}},"styling":{"selectedTextBgColor":{"mode":"@d{ic3.color_mode.single_color}","colors":["#1a9641","#a6d96a","#ffffbf","#fdae61","#d7191c"],"isDefaultPalette":false,"color":"#61b8ac"}},"selectionMode":"single"},"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"data-render","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false}},"user-menu":{"classID":"ic3.WidgetSettings","guts_":{"data":{},"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"user-menu","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false}},"filtering":{"classID":"ic3.WidgetSettings","guts_":{"data":{},"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"filtering","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false}}}}},"ic3_name":"w12","ic3_eventMapper":{"classID":"ic3.EventWidgetMapper","guts_":{"ic3selection":"region","__ic3_widgetEventsDescription":{}}},"ic3_uid":"w9"}},"w10":{"classID":"ic3.AmChartsAdapter","guts_":{"configState":3,"dataRenderOptions":{"chartType":{"label":"Clustered","proto":{"chartPrototype":{"type":"serial","categoryAxis":{"id":"CategoryAxis","gridPosition":"start"},"valueAxes":[{"id":"ValueAxis-1"}],"legend":{"enabled":false,"useGraphSettings":true},"chartCursor":{"enabled":false},"chartScrollbar":{"enabled":false}},"graphPrototype":{"balloonText":"[[Row]], [[Column]]: [[FValue]]","connect":false,"type":"column","fillAlphas":1,"lineThickness":0},"guidePrototype":{"expand":true,"labelRotation":0,"position":"top","tickLength":5},"dataProviderType":0},"id":"serial-chart-clustered"},"graphsConfiguration":[{"xAxis":{},"yAxis":{},"colorMode":{"mode":"@d{ic3.color_mode.single_color}","colors":[],"mdxMeasure":"Value","isDefaultPalette":true,"color":"#61b8ac"}}],"valueAxes":[],"trendLinesGuides":{},"configuredQuadrants":{},"advanced":{}},"widgetSettingsManager":{"classID":"ic3.AmChartsSettingsManager","guts_":{"desktop":{"data-render":{"classID":"ic3.WidgetSettings","guts_":{"data":{"chartType":{"label":"Clustered","proto":{"chartPrototype":{"type":"serial","categoryAxis":{"id":"CategoryAxis","gridPosition":"start"},"valueAxes":[{"id":"ValueAxis-1"}],"legend":{"enabled":false,"useGraphSettings":true},"chartCursor":{"enabled":false},"chartScrollbar":{"enabled":false}},"graphPrototype":{"balloonText":"[[Row]], [[Column]]: [[FValue]]","connect":false,"type":"column","fillAlphas":1,"lineThickness":0},"guidePrototype":{"expand":true,"labelRotation":0,"position":"top","tickLength":5},"dataProviderType":0},"id":"serial-chart-clustered"},"graphsConfiguration":[{"xAxis":{},"yAxis":{},"colorMode":{"mode":"@d{ic3.color_mode.single_color}","colors":[],"mdxMeasure":"Value","isDefaultPalette":true,"color":"#61b8ac"}}],"valueAxes":[],"trendLinesGuides":{},"configuredQuadrants":{},"advanced":{}},"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"data-render","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false}},"data":{"classID":"ic3.QueryBuilderWidgetSettings","guts_":{"data":{"builderUid":"m6"},"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"data","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false}},"events":{"classID":"ic3.EventMapperWidgetSettings","guts_":{"data":{"classID":"ic3.EventWidgetMapper","guts_":{"__ic3_widgetEventsDescription":{}}},"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"events","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false}},"navigation":{"classID":"ic3.NavigationWidgetSettings","guts_":{"data":{"classID":"ic3.AmChartsNavigationStrategy","guts_":{"menuVisibility":{"back":true,"axisXChange":"All","axisYChange":"All","filter":"All","reset":true,"widget":true,"others":"All"},"selectionMode":"disabled"}},"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"navigation","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false}},"hooks":{"classID":"ic3.WidgetSettings","guts_":{"data":{},"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"hooks","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false}},"filtering":{"classID":"ic3.WidgetSettings","guts_":{"data":{},"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"filtering","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false}},"user-menu":{"classID":"ic3.WidgetSettings","guts_":{"layoutKey":"desktop","settingsKey":"user-menu","useDefaultLayoutSettings":false}}}}},"ic3_uid":"w10","ic3_name":"w10","ic3_eventMapper":{"classID":"ic3.EventWidgetMapper","guts_":{"__ic3_widgetEventsDescription":{}}}}}}},"queries":{"classID":"ic3.MdxQueriesContainerMgr","guts_":{"mdxQueries":{"classID":"ic3.BaseContainerMgr","guts_":{"items":[{"classID":"ic3.QueryBuilderWidget","guts_":{"mode":"MDX","schemaSettings":{"cubeName":null,"schemaName":null},"options":{"WIZARD":{"measures":[],"rows":[],"rowsNonEmpty":false,"columns":[],"columnsNonEmpty":false,"filter":[]},"MDX":{"statement":"WITH\n  MEMBER [Measures].[Difference Previous Day] AS PercN( [Measures].[Count] , ( [Time].[Year].prevMember , [Measures].[Count] ) ) , FORMAT_STRING=\"percent\"\n  MEMBER [Measures].[IconName] AS CASE\n    WHEN [Product].[Product].currentMember is [Product].[Product].[Category].[License] THEN \"fa-cubes\"\n    ELSE \"fa-phone\" END\nSELECT\n  {[Measures].[Count],[Measures].[Difference Previous Day],[Measures].[IconName]} ON 0,\n  {[Product].[Product].[Category]} on 1\nFROM (SELECT @{region!∅} ON 0 FROM [Sales])\nWHERE [Time].[Year].[2007]"},"DATASOURCE":{}},"ic3_name":"mdx Query-1","ic3_uid":"m3"}},{"classID":"ic3.QueryBuilderWidget","guts_":{"mode":"WIZARD","schemaSettings":{"cubeName":null,"schemaName":null},"options":{"WIZARD":{"measures":[{"name":"Amount","subType":null,"memberBase":{"hierarchy":"[Measures]","level":"[Measures].[MeasuresLevel]","members":["[Measures].[Amount]"]},"hierarchy":"[Measures]","level":"[Measures].[MeasuresLevel]"}],"rows":[{"name":"","memberBase":{"hierarchy":"[Product].[Product]","level":"[Product].[Product].[Article]","members":[]},"order":{"measure":"[Measures].[Amount]","direction":"BDESC"},"nonEmpty":{"measure":"[Measures].[Amount]"}}],"rowsNonEmpty":false,"columns":[],"columnsNonEmpty":false,"filter":[{"memberBase":{"mdx":"@{row}"},"mandatory":false},{"memberBase":{"mdx":"@{region}"},"mandatory":false}]},"MDX":{},"DATASOURCE":{}},"ic3_name":"mdx Query-0","ic3_uid":"m6"}}]}},"mdxFilter":{"classID":"ic3.BaseContainerMgr","guts_":{"items":[{"classID":"ic3.FilterQueryBuilder","guts_":{"mode":"WIZARD","schemaSettings":{},"options":{"WIZARD":{"filter":[],"setAxis":[{"name":null,"memberBase":{"hierarchy":"[Customers].[Geography]","level":"[Customers].[Geography].[Region]","members":[]}}],"addDefaultMember":true,"clientPreselection":null},"MDX":{"statement":null},"MANUAL":{"items":[]},"DATASOURCE":{}},"ic3_name":"mdx Filter-0","ic3_uid":"m1"}}]}},"actionBuilders":{"classID":"ic3.BaseContainerMgr","guts_":{"items":[]}}}},"javascript":{"classID":"ic3.ReportJavascriptMgr","guts_":{"js":"/**                                                                      \n * A function called each time an event is generated.                    \n *                                                                       \n * @param context the same object is passed between consumeEvent calls.  \n *                Can be used to store information.                      \n *        {                                                              \n *          $report   : jQuery context of the report container           \n *          fireEvent : a function( name, value ) triggering an event    \n *        }                                                              \n *                                                                       \n * @param event the event information                                    \n *                                                                       \n          {                                                              \n *          name  : as specified in the 'Events' tab                     \n *          value : (optional) actual event value                        \n *          type  : (optional) e.g., ic3selection                        \n *        }                                                              \n *                                                                       \n * Check the 'Report Event Names' menu for the list of available events. \n */                                                                      \n/*                                                                       \nfunction consumeEvent( context, event ) {                                \n  if (event.name == 'ic3-report-init') {                                 \n    // add your code here                                                \n  }                                                                      \n}                                                                        \n*/                                                                       \n"}},"css":{"classID":"ic3.CssMgr","guts_":{"content":".ic3a-container .ic3a-mini-box-c .ic3a-mini-box:hover,\n.ic3a-container .ic3a-mini-box-c .ic3a-mini-box.iv-selected:hover\n{\n  background: #03A9F4  !important;\n  color: white  !important;\n}\n\n.ic3a-container .ic3a-mini-box-c .ic3a-mini-box.iv-selected {\n  background: #81D4FA !important;\n  color: white  !important;\n}\n"}},"constants":{"classID":"ic3.ConstantsMgr","guts_":{}},"calculatedMeasures":{"classID":"ic3.CalcMeasureMgr","guts_":{"measures":[]}},"localizations":[]},"generators":{"widgetIdGenerator":{"magic":"ic3sv1","classID":"ic3.EntityIdGenerator","guts":{"incrementalIndex":11,"prefix":"w"}},"widgetBoxIdGenerator":{"magic":"ic3sv1","classID":"ic3.EntityIdGenerator","guts":{"incrementalIndex":108,"prefix":"wb"}}}}}